# Llamar resultado de variable desde template

Tags: python, django

estoy queriendo mostrar en mi página un contador de usuarios registrados, pero no logro hacer que se muestre en el template, ya que no se como llamar la variable que da la cantidad de usuarios que tengo en mi web..

Yo lo que tengo en views.py es lo siguiente

```
class CantUser(ListView):
    users = User.objects.all()
    cant = (len(users))
    print(cant)
```

Hice un print ahi para ver si funcionaba, pues en consola muestra bien la cantidad de usuarios, pero la idea es mostrarla en mi web. No se si esta sea la forma correcta de mostrar la cantidad de usuarios registrados o no.

Gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 1):

El método get_context_data debe retornar las variables que quieres usar en el template, algo así:

```
class CantUserView(ListView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    template_name = 'tu_app/nombre_template.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # agrega cant, asi puede usar esta variable en el template
        context['cant'] = self.queryset.count()
        return context
```

Mira la documentación en https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context

Evita usar len(QuerySet), mejor usa el método count() del queryset, es mucho más eficiente.

También debes colocar esta vista en el urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^cant-user/', CantUserView.as_view(), name='cant_user'),
]
```

Comment: hola, pues puse {{ cant }} en mi template y no me lo toma, disculpa es que recién estoy comenzando con django.

Comment: Definir el template_name en la vista, incluir la vista en el urls.py, ya agregue esos asuntos en la anterior respuesta. Si quiere publica la app a github y te puede decir que más hace falta.